# How do you remove data labels in matplotlib_venn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn

Not the text labels outside the circles, I can remove them by changing them to empty strings.

I mean the actual numbers on the circles showing the value of each patch. I can't find how to remove these. Is there a way? Or is there a way to change the colour of them, so that I can just blend them into the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrowing the "base-code" from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426075/how-to-modify-the-font-size-in-matplotlib-venn) I think I have come to a solution for you:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles
set1 = set(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
set2 = set(['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
set3 = set(['C', 'D',' E', 'F', 'G'])

out = venn3([set1, set2, set3], ('Set1', 'Set2', 'Set3'))
for idx, subset in enumerate(out.subset_labels):
    out.subset_labels[idx].set_visible(False)

plt.show(out)
```

This walks through all of the `subset_labels` and sets the `visibility` to `False`. Effectively removing the text.